# for loop with a predefined value as counter

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, predefined-variables

I'm working on my program when I tried a for loop with a predefined integer.

```
int row = 0;
[...]
//row = 50
for(row = 0; row < y; row++)
{
    [...]
}
```

For whatever reason, even if I specify that "row = 0;" before the while loop the code just doesn't give a sensible output. This however works just fine:

```
for(int temprow = 0; temprow < y; temprow++)
{
    row = temprow;
    [...]
}
```

What gives?

Comment: Why do you need a for? Try to use WHILE! I think so it is the better option to your case!

Comment: Just used to using a for loop when knowing the amount of times it should run. Habit I guess.

Comment: What do you mean by _the code just doesn't give a sensible output_. What output do you expect and what output do you get?

Comment: Well I'm working on a maze solver, I made one previously, however I'm trying to optimise it and improve on it. This part of the code is for initialising the maze. However the first line only adds exit nodes, rather than nodes throughout the entire maze, which baffles me.

Comment: This looks a bit like an XY problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem. I am pretty sure what you have distilled out is not the real problem.